# Extension from OLED display to driver board

Tags: display, prototyping, oled, fpc, ffc

I have purchased this display for a prototype in development.

Product: https://www.displaymodule.com/collections/oled/products/2-8-256x64-monochrome-graphic-oled-display-module-spi-mpu

Datasheet: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gxOVcEEhbBCdMktJI8cXT_XhS1yv98Ft/view

Due to the limitations in the assembly of the prototype, the screen needs to be separated from the board. Because of the orientation of the parts, this means the FPC (apologies if this is the wrong term) cable cannot reach the connector on the board (see image, white tab is back of connector from screen, needs to get to receiver on blue board).

[image: photo showing connectors]

I need to source a female to male extension for this to make the assembly feasible, but do not have good knowledge with this type of connector.

Is anyone able to provide advice on what type of extension I could utilise and where it can be sourced from?

Please let me know if any further details are required.

Comment: I think you should cut out the steel, or to mount the entire display on the other side. The frequency is high, so extending the flat cable may not work. Look  at it as the finished product, not to be disassembled.

Answer (score 1):

Yes these are FPC defined by pitch, # contacts thickness. and length. Search for those parameters on Mouser,or D-K will help narrow it down or call their tech support.

[Here are some...](https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/filter/flat-flex-jumpers-cables-ffc-fpc/458?s=N4IgjCBcoBwJxVAYygMwIYBsDOBTANCAPZQDaIArAExhUgC6hADgC5QgDKLATgJYB2AcxABfQmDjxEIFJAw4CxMiAAMDZm0iceA4WJABaOtBlQeAV0UlI5CupCt2okSKA)

Comment: Okay thanks heaps for the info, will get in touch with the tech support through those sites

Comment: the ones you linked to appear to be correct but judging from the datasheet it is a 30 pin FPC? this appears to be non standard, am I chasing a red herring potentially here?

Comment: FPC’s come in many track sizes.